# How to animate grid rotation by compass data ? c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, augmented-reality

I am creating an augmented reality app for wp8. It looks something like the image shown below.[image]

The black screen will be filled by video source from cam. And for the small circle in the top left, I am using two grids one upon another. First grid contains the limegreen segment, this grid will be stationary. Second grid contains the bigger circle with the letter N on top. This must rotate to show the north direction by taking the data from device compass.

I followed the below given article to mimic the production of compass. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202974(v=vs.105).aspx

But in the timer_Tick event, I must update the rotation of the brownish grid with the letter N. I am completely clueless on how to obtain the realtime rotation of the grid from the compass data. How can I use storyboard to do feed the angle ? Or is there any simpler way without starting and stopping storyboard and all the fuss ?

The grid xaml code is given below.

```
<Grid Name="StationaryLittleMap" Width="150" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,0">
            <Path Stroke="White" Fill="LimeGreen" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigureCollection>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="38,10">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <PathSegmentCollection>
                                            <ArcSegment Size="75,75" RotationAngle="36" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="112,10" />
                                            <LineSegment Point="75,75" />
                                            <LineSegment Point="38,10" />
                                        </PathSegmentCollection>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathFigureCollection>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="MoveLittleMap" Width="150" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,0" >
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange"  Height="150" Width="150"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.4" />
            <TextBlock Text="N" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested by the animation, you can directly update the CompositeTransform.

First, give it a name in the XAML:

```
<CompositeTransform x:Name="CompassTransform" />
```

Then, change the angle directly from the code:

```
this.CompassTransform.Rotation = 45;
```

But if you want the compass to rotate smoothly, then you have no other choice than using a storyboard.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try out both the storyboard and direct transform and see what suits my requirements. Thanks :)